# Variable in request body replaced with {} during POST

Tags: rest, karate

I'm using Karate DSL (version 0.6.1.1), and I have the following scenario:

```
  Scenario:
    Given url baseURL
    * def email = "test_email@test_domain.com"
    * def query = "SELECT * FROM public.users where username='" + email + "' ORDER BY user_id ASC"
    * def dbUrl = databaseUrl + "databaseName"
    * def config = { username: '#(databaseUsername)', password: '#(databasePassword)', url: '#(dbUrl)', driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver' }
    * def DbUtils = Java.type('utility.database.DbUtils')
    * def db = new DbUtils(config)
    * def results = db.readRow(query)
    * def supplierId = results.user_id
    * print "SUPPLIERID: " + supplierId

    Given path '/path/to/endpoint'
    And header content-type = 'application/json'
    And request { supplierId: #(supplierId) }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

`utility.database.DbUtils` is a custom class and `readRow()` is a single line member of that class that returns the result of [`JdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap-java.lang.String-).

Running this scenario gives the following log:

```
    10:53:17.477 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] SUPPLIERID: 957750e7-ee6b-486d-977c-05c8ac7bb589
    10:53:17.506 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - request:{
      "supplierId": 957750e7-ee6b-486d-977c-05c8ac7bb589
    }
    10:53:18.372 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 
    1 > POST http://baseurl.com/path/to/endpoint
    1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
    1 > Content-Length: 17
    1 > Content-Type: application/json
    1 > Host: base.url.com
    1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_162)
    {"supplierId":{}}
```

You can see that at first the request body has the value of `supplierId` as `957750e7-ee6b-486d-977c-05c8ac7bb589`.  Once the POST is made though, `supplierId` is just `{}`.  This seems to have something to do with the fact that `supplierId` is populated by a database call.  If I replace the call to the database with a simple `* def supplierId = "957750e7-ee6b-486d-977c-05c8ac7bb589"`, the request body appears as expected.

Why is `supplierId` replaced with `{}` when the POST call is made, and how do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a type conversion issue.  I got it working by replacing `* def supplierId = results.user_id` with `* string supplierId = results.user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got the embedded expression syntax wrong. I think this one change should fix, note the string-quotes:

```
And request { supplierId: '#(supplierId)' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still get the same result with the quotes, though.

Comment: ok, this falls into the "works for me" category. no idea what your json is but a guess, try: `* def supplierId = results.user_id.supplierId` - if that fails only thing left I can suggest, follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue